# SOAP or REST? Which one to use please?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm starting to learn DocuSign to see how I can integrate it into our current solution and I need your help to pick which SOA technology to use?  I know how to use both SOAP and REST and I'll use Java.

My manager asked me to select one technology to use and I need reasons to tell him why I pick one technology over the other.  Here are my questions to pick one over the other.

1) Does DocuSign offer the same services for both SOAP and REST?  In other words, it does not matter which technology I use, I still be able to access all services DocuSign offers???

2) Simplicity - I heard REST is simpler than SOAP???

3) Any other reasons that you have, please let me know.

Which technology do you recommend for me to use please, SOAP or REST?

Thanks

Comment: There are far more technologies out there than just SOAP and REST.

Comment: I recommend using JSONRPC!

Answer (score 2):

From the DocuSign perspective, it comes down to personal preference (REST vs SOAP) for the most part -- there's no single compelling/mandatory reason that you would necessarily have to choose one over the other.  That being said, here are some thoughts, in no particular order:

- The DocuSign SOAP API has been around longer; the DocuSign REST API is much newer. Recently, it seems, new operations are oftentimes being added only to the REST API (and not to the SOAP API. (See the first paragraph here: http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/soap-api)
- The operations (i.e., features/functionality) available in the DocuSign SOAP API versus the DocuSign REST API are largely the same -- but the APIs are by no means 1:1 in terms of operations/features/functionality -- there are differences between the two.
- There's no reason why you can't mix SOAP and REST within your implementation. i.e., Let's say you're most comfortable working with REST, so you choose that.  If you discover at some point that you need an operation that's only available in SOAP, then just make that one call using the SOAP API -- leaving all the remaining calls using REST.
- DocuSign SOAP API Requests tend to be larger in size than DocuSign REST API Requests -- which is fairly typical of any SOAP versus REST comparison.
- The DocuSign SOAP API might be considered more powerful (efficient?) in some ways, in that there are things you can do with a single DocuSign SOAP API call that can only be achieved by making multiple DocuSign REST API calls.

I'd recommend that you checkout the DocuSign Developer Center for more information about the DocuSign APIs:  http://www.docusign.com/developer-center

Comment: SOAP is really bloatware. Compared to REST it usually about doubles the size of each message. More importantly than bytes, I have seen the performance between SOAP and REST differing by factor(!) 10 or more. (And there are even better alternatives than REST, but I doubt that DocuSign supports them) The exact numbers depend on the framework and on your use case, but the tendency is there. If traffic/throughput is not the main issue, choose the stable API. Otherwise choose REST, or implement both (no issue with good tooling).